# Recyclerview dont show images

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

i have been trying to display images in my recyclerview, i had seen a lot of tutorials, but i can't.

this is my onBindViewholder in my  adapter class

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final cowviewHolder holder, int position) {
       final Cow vacaslist = vacas.get(position);
       holder.textViewinterno.setText(vacaslist.interno);
       holder.textViewsiniiga.setText(vacaslist.siniiga);
      Picasso.get().load(vacaslist.ulr)
               .resize(80,80).centerCrop().error(R.drawable.ic_imageinf).into(holder.imageviewrec);
```

This is my database in firebase, im taking the images from storage

[image]

Thanks.. If need more info let me know

Comment: Are you certain that the url is correct, log it down, and open it in browser

Comment: yes, I can open them in the browser without problem. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/postid-471e4.appspot.com/o/1717.jpg?alt=media&token=c3f891d3-b403-488a-8b9e-c5d97b3d7f59

Comment: can you share the list item layout

Comment: I've added the object cow, if that's what you mean

Comment: I mean the xml file of the recyclerview list item

Comment: shared the layer item

Comment: `Picasso.get().load(vacaslist.ulr)` are you sure it is `vacaslist.ulr` ? not `vacaslist.url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your `ulr` variable name because on firebase it is `url` so, if you are instantiating your `Cow` object using following syntax:

```
ref.child("Vacas").child("$id").getValue(Cow.class);
```

Then ulr will be null.